# Group hierarchy in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, groups, rbac

Is it possible to get group hierarchy in AD? It's for managing permissions to a web app from there.

I need to do this:

- Users

  - Product

    - Admin

      - Task

        - Subtask1
        - Subtask2
        - Subtask3
      - Task 2

So if you are member of Admin you get reference to Task and Task 2 and its children. I think that AD doesn't come with an RBAC hierarchy but I want to be sure.

Comment: I think you're asking if Active Directory supports nested groups; It does. Is there something specific you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi, yes, I need to be member of Task and with a Query, know its childs. If I am member of Task, I should be member of Subtasks1,2,3. Thanks

Comment: Yes, in that configuration, you would be a member (but not a direct member) of all the subtask groups. It's up to the application talking to AD to do its group lookups using recursion (or not).

Comment: Could you give me a link, an example or something to lead me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Here's an example of getting nested groups - http://serverfault.com/questions/429981/view-parents-of-many-nested-sub-groups-in-active-directory/429990#429990 - If you need a specific example, just edit your question and I'll try to help.

Comment: Is it only available for C# ? I need to it on PHP

Comment: If you're using LDAP filter syntax to query the groups, it should be the same regardless of the language. For PHP specific examples, you may want to search on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your app supports recursive lookups, or if youre doing this with simple filesystem permissions, yes, that is possible.

What you need to do is to make each parent a member of its direct children. For example, Admin would be a member of Task and Task 2, Task would be a member of Subtask1, Subtask2, and Subtask3. You would then add users to a single group and they would have all the privilege of the subgroups.